# Get Full Exception Error with Flex

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript, exception, trace

I can't use trace because I'm not using an Adobe IDE and when I try to view my exception errors, I can't seem to get the full error message, I only seem to get the "errorID". For example, if I had a 1069 error, I should see something like:

> Error #1069: Property data not found on **X** and
>   there is no default value.

But instead I see this...

> ReferenceError: Error #1069

This is my code...

```
try
{
//error gets thrown here
}
catch(e:Error)
{
extTrace('Error: '+e.toString());//I also tried e.message, e.name & ObjectUtil.toString(e.getStackTrace())
}
```

This is just a function for simplifying logging to console.  I'm not sure if it's the reason for the issue or not, due to console.log(''), but whatever...

```
private function extTrace(traceString:String):void
{
ExternalInterface.call("console.log('"+traceString+"')");
}
```

I also tried e.message, e.name & ObjectUtil.toString(e.getStackTrace())

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the full error message, you need to test in debug mode; it looks like you're running in release, which removes a lot of debug symbols

Comment: How do I run an embedded swf in debug mode?

Comment: @PolishHurricane Download and install the Flash debug player from Adobe [here](http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html). Then, when compiling the SWF you opt to compile a debug version, rather than the optimized release version.

Comment: @PolishHurricane What are you using to actually write and test your code?

Comment: I'm using Sublime Text 2 w/Flex to Build and I'm just testing in a web browser.
@SunilD. Thanks, I'm going to try that when I get a chance.

Comment: @PolishHurricane based on the tools you're using, it sounds like you compiling from the command line using `mxmlc` from the Flex SDK. If so, you might find [this page](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7a92.html) helpful (shows options you can pass to `mxmlc` ... in particular the `-debug=true` option would be useful).

Comment: if you're testing in a web browser, make sure you're using the debug player. you can check this easily by right-clicking on the swf; if you see an option "Show redraw regions", then it's the debug player. If you don't see this, then depending on your browser (notably Chrome) you'll need to go through different steps to get it installed

Comment: You can also test it by building the swf, and just opening it in the debug standalone player, that you can download above. tbh, the easiest way, is to use FlashDevelop or FlashBuilder depending on your platform; then you get full debugger support

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, I installed that debug plugin and it's working great now.  I get console output now too.  w00t!

Answer (score 0):

In your try-catch block you get an object of type Error. That object has a method getStackTrace - http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Error.html#getStackTrace()

Comment: I did "ObjectUtil.toString(e.getStackTrace())", but I got nothing, is that wrong?

Comment: Hm ... that's strange. You should get the stack trace.