# Error Message not generated

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flex4

1 - Build flex on **Windows 7 64 bits**, and when error is thrown, i can get both the **error code** and **error Message**

```
2015/06/15 16:47:26:192 [ERROR] MyClass Error: Error #3013: File or directory is in use.
                at flash.filesystem::FileStream/open()
                at MyClass/openCsv()
                ...
```

2 - Build flex on **Windows 2008 R2 64 Bits**, and when error is thrown, i can get **only the error code**, but **not the error message**

```
2015/06/15 17:15:17:215 [ERROR] MyClass Error: Error #3013
                at MyClass/openCsv()
                ...
```

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was not due to the operating system 
The response is : We can get the error message only in debug mode, but not in production mode

Also, you can take a look to the previous answers:
[Get Full Exception Error with Flex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18951933/get-full-exception-error-with-flex)